# Covert a column of string dates

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have 2 columns in access that are saved as string dates yyyymmdd.  I am linking the table to a oracle database and need to coveret the columns on insert to look like yyyy/mm/dd.

I am trying:

```
INSERT INTO TEST
(DATE) Values (20110818, To_DATE("YYYY/MM/DD"))
FROM TEST_DATE
```

I want to convert the entire column on insert from access into oracle

Comment: Surely you need to convert your date to a date not to a it.string? By the way _do not_ call a column date. Untold hassle awaits you if you try

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391389/insert-into-select-from-access-to-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
INSERT INTO TEST
(DATE) 
SELECT TO_DATE('20110818','YYYYMMDD')
FROM TEST_DATE
```

Comment: By the way, '20110818' must be a field of TEST_DATE table.

Comment: No, `'20110818'` is a string. You're inserting the date `18/08/2011` into the table `test`, however many times there are records in `test_date`

Comment: Why are you selecting '200110818' string from table? You can use just  VALUES statement.

Comment: Did you mean too ask the OP not me? :-).

Comment: :) i just realized that you are not the one that asked question.. I just commented answer bcouse it has no mean selecting static string from table.