# INSERT INTO SELECT FROM ACCESS TO ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have a table in Access named TEST_DATE1 with the column TEST_DATE that is a String datatype and the records look like 20080130.  yyyymmdd

I have a table in Oracle named TEST with the column TEST_DATE that is a DATE datatype and I want the records to look like 2008/01/30 yyyy/mm/dd.

I have the two tables linked and when I usually update tables between Access and Oracle I usually do a

```
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT *
FROM TEST_DATE1;
```

How would you convert the string to a DATE using the INSERT INTO SELECT

I have tried

```
INSERT INTO TEST
(SELECT TO_DATE(TEST_DATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
FROM TEST_DATE1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you have 'tried' this sql, what result or error are you receiving?

Comment: But your format in test_date1 is 'YYYMMDD', right? (minus the slashes).  It sounds like you are trying to combine two separate steps.  The first thing you want to do is convert from your old format.  It will be stored as a date in Oracle and you can select from that table and get the format you want upon retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the records to Oracle, converting a string to a date:

```
INSERT INTO test (test_date)
SELECT TO_DATE(test_date, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM test_date1
```

Once it's in Oracle stored as a date, you can retrieve it in any format you like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(test_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as test_date
FROM test;
```

Comment: How is your link defined?  What environment are you executing your SQL in?

Comment: @user1307149 I assumed your db link was in Oracle and that's where you were running your SQL.  Since I'm not an Access expert, I can't really help you unless you want to do it from the Oracle side.

Comment: MY DB LINK IS TO Oracle From Access and I am executing the sql query in Access

Comment: The dates are stored as strings in Access and I am trying to move them to a oracle DATE column.

Comment: I Got it:                                                            INSERT INTO TEST ( TEST_DATE )
SELECT CDate(Mid(TEST_DATE, 5,2) & "/" & Right(TEST_DATE, 2) & "/" & Left(TEST_DATE, 4))
FROM TEST_DATE1;